# How to change a color for dynamically created buttons in a gridview

Tags: java, android, gridview

Hello I was using this tutorial in order to create an arraylist of button description that would allow me to create the buttons.
http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/09/android-creating-a-custom-adapter-for-gridview-buttonadapter/

```
public class CategoryButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<DishCategory> dishCategories;
//button to be created
private Button button;
//will take in an array list created in the orderlayout that will be the 
//dish category. This will be the from where we will the count for the adapter
public CategoryButtonAdapter(ArrayList<DishCategory> dishCategories)
{
    this.dishCategories = dishCategories;
}
public CategoryButtonAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DishCategory> dishCategories)
{
    this.mContext = context;
    this.dishCategories = dishCategories;
}

public int getCount() 
{
    return dishCategories.size();
}

//to be implementated later so it can b3e used to find menu categories
public Object getItem(int position) 
{
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) 
{
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    //button to be created
    if(convertView == null )
    {
        //if it is not recycled, initialize some new attributes
        button = new Button(this.mContext);
        button.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100,100));
        button.setPadding(2,2,2,2);
    }
    else
    {
        button = (Button) convertView;
    }
    //setButton to the description of the category
    button.setText(dishCategories.get(position).getDescription());

    //this can be changed later to change the sex appeal of the app
    //for now it will be plain
    button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    button.setHighlightColor (Color.GREEN);
    button.setId(position);
    button.setOnClickListener(new DishCategoryButtonListener(button.getId()));
    //new loadDishItems(categoryButtons.get(position).getDescription()));
    return button;
}
```

Now it is able to create the buttons as wished when called upon in the main activity.
Here is my custom onclicklistener
class

```
    DishCategoryButtonListener implements OnClickListener
    {
        private final int position;

        private DishCategoryButtonListener(int position) {
            this.position = position;
        }

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            System.out.println("The position is " + position);

            //button.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            //button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
```

The issue I would run into is that whenever I selected a button on the screen. It would show me the correct position, but for some reason it does not change color to green and black if it was selected. I want it to be green if selected and black if it is not. Is there a way I could do this? Would I have to implement the onclick listener in the main class or would I have to use this custom listener?

**EDIT**I just tried that and instead what I have seen is a pattern. Lets say the list contains about 20 objects in the array list. This then creates 20 buttons in a 1 column gridview. What seems to be happening is that whenever on of them is clicked, it actually changes the color of the button at the bottom of screen. If I scroll down, it changes the color of that button at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to implement the OnClickListener inline in getView?

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View button) {
      button.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
      button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
  }
}
```

I don't know exactly why, but I had similar Issues where this helped.

Comment: I just tried that and instead what I have seen is a pattern. Lets say the list contains about 20 objects in the array list. This then creates 20 buttons in a 1 column gridview. What seems to be happening is that whenever on of them is clicked, it actually changes the color of the button at the bottom of screen. If I scroll down, it changes the color of that button at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that you don't use a Holder Pattern! This is very easy to implement and very important for you performance of the list. Please read here: http://www.jmanzano.es/blog/?p=166

What happens now: During the creation of your 20 items the button variable always gets the overridden with the currently created list item. That's why your bottom item is the one that gets always changed: It was the last one created.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code into the event dispatch thread -- easiest in this case might be to use SwingUtilities.invokeLater().

```
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {

        System.out.println("The position is " + position);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater
        (
          new Runnable()
          {
             public void run()
             {
                button.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
             }
          }
        );
    }
```